# Algoritmo com estrutura PARA e SE

Tags: algoritmo, portugol, visualg

Um algoritmo que leia o nome e o sexo de cinquenta e seis pessoas e informe o nome e se ela é homem ou mulher. No final informe o total de homens e mulheres.
Preciso que o programa rode no VisualG.

Fiz este código mas ele não tá funcionando:

```
// Função :
// Autor :
// Data : 29/09/2015
// Seção de Declarações 
var
nome , sexo , feminino, masculino: literal
i : inteiro
inicio
escreva ("Digite seu nome: ", nome)
leia (nome)
escreva ("Digite seu sexo: ", sexo)
leia (sexo)
para i <- 1 ate 56 faca
se (sexo = feminino) entao
  escreva ("Seu nome é: ",nome "e seu sexo é: feminino", feminino)

fimse
fimpara
fimalgoritmo
```

Eu preciso que além de ler o nome e o sexo de 56 pessoas informe o nome e se ela é homem ou mulher e no final informe o total dos homens e das mulheres, mas não consigo fazer com que o código funcione.

Comment: Bem-vindo ao **SOpt**. Aqui nós respondemos perguntas, não fazemos o seu trabalho da faculdade. Clique em [edit] e coloque a sua dúvida, sobre algo em específico. Caso queira entender como o site funciona recomendo fazer o [tour] dar uma olhada na [help]. Também veja [Como criar um exemplo Mínimo, Completo e Verificável](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Pois é, Cristina, aqui você encontra um arquivo gigante de informações, é só pesquisar. E para contribuir fazendo perguntas e receber retribuição na forma de resposta certeira, vai precisar caprichar mais na hora de escrever a pergunta. É só **[edit]** e acrescentar detalhes do que você tentou, o que deu errado e qual é exatamente sua dúvida de programação.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nunca usei o VisualG, mas creio que seu código deva ficar assim

```
var 
nome , sexo: literal
i, c, fem, masc : inteiro

inicio
  para c <- 1 ate 56 faca

    nome := ""
    sexo := "" 

    escreval ("Digite seu nome:")
    leia (nome)
    escreval ("Digite seu sexo (masculino/feminino):")
    leia (sexo)

    se(sexo = "feminino")
      fem := fem + 1
    senao
      masc := masc + 1
    fimse

    escreval("Seu nome é ", nome, " e seu sexo é ", sexo)
  fimpara    

escreval("foram cadastrados ", fem, " mulheres e ", masc, " homens")

fimalgoritmo
```

Tem algumas coisas que dá para melhorar, como por exemplo, validar para não aceitar entradas diferentes de **masculino** e **feminino** no sexo, mas já tá bem melhor do que o código da pergunta.

Comment: esse deu quase certo, por exemplo se eu coloco o nome : Ana e sexo feminino ele fica aparecendo só ana e sexo feminino não dá pra colocar outro nome nem outro sexo

Comment: como faço pra fazer o campo limpar ? por exemplo coloquei ana e sexo feminino e quero que apareça pra mim digitar mais que não apareça ana lá, o que fazer?

Comment: o programa já tá 98% funcionando mais tem um problema quando eu executo ele aparece assim :"  seu nome é André e o seu sexo é: masculino digite seu nome " tudo na mesma linha como faço pra colocar o digite seu nome na linha seguinte

Comment: Troque os `escreva` por `escreval` que imprimirá cada comando numa linha

Comment: poxa cara muito obrigada :) o código agora tá 100%

Answer (score 5):

Dá para melhorar, mas isto funciona:

```
var
nome, sexo: caractere
i, m, f : inteiro
inicio
m <- 0
f <- 0
para i <- 1 ate 56 faca
  escreva("Digite seu nome: ")
  leia(nome)
  escreva("Digite seu sexo (m/f): ")
  leia(sexo)
  se (sexo = "f") entao
    escreval("Seu nome é: ", nome, " e seu sexo é: feminino")
    f <- f + 1
  senao
    escreval("Seu nome é: ", nome, " e seu sexo é: masculino")
    m <- m + 1
  fimse
fimpara
escreval("Total de mulheres: ", f)
escreval("Total de mulheres: ", m)
fimalgoritmo
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Portugol/Basic.ptg).

Entre os vários problemas inclusive de sintaxe da linguagem, não estava pegando os dados 56 vezes como a descrição pedia, então acrescentei um laço nesta parte. E fiz imprimir quando é masculino que não fazia.

Comment: esse a sintaxe não funciona, só coloca nome e o sexo e depois para de rodar

Comment: Dê mais informações. Eu não tenho o Visualg então não posso testar. Mas erro de sintaxe é mais fácil de achar quando se sabe qual é ele.

Comment: Começa a dar erro daqui escreval("Seu nome é: ", nome "e seu sexo é: feminino")
    f <- f + 1

Comment: Eu já tinha arrumado isto. Agora arrumei outra coisa que eu vi que não está usando vetor, estou tão acostumado com esses exercícios tendo que fiz como se tivesse. Como não tem a solução é fazer um laço só.

Comment: como que faço pra apagar um campo? o código fica repetindo o mesmo nome e o mesmo sexo não apaga, exemplo: se eu digito nome Ana e sexo feminino quando é pra mim digitar o próximo aparece ana e não dá pra apagar

Comment: Eu duvido que aconteça isto, não deveria, tem alguma coisa diferente no seu código. Se quiser insistir em fazer isto teria que colocar no início ou no final do laço as linhas `nome <- ""` e `sexo <- ""`. Tem que ser dentro do laço. Mas reforço que não precisa fazer isto. Mesmo não sabendo usar o Visualg :D

Comment: Acho que ela estava se referindo à minha resposta, que estava realmente imprimindo as variáveis `nome` e `sexo` quando perguntava.

Comment: É, essa "pergunta" tá bem confusa de ponta a ponta :)

Comment: @KCristina copie o código do jeito que está e me diga se tem alguma coisa errada ainda ou se deu tudo certo.

Comment: eu consegui achar o erro, tava no meu código logo após o para

Comment: @KCristina eu consegui testar agora e o código está funcionando redondinho fazendo tudo que está descrito, sem quebrar, sem repetir informação, pilando linhas, contando direito, etc.

Comment: está sim, muito obrigado ficou ótimo o código

Answer (score 0):

```
algoritmo "semnome"

// Função :

// Autor :

// Data : 09/02/2016

// Seção de Declarações 

var

nome, sexo, f, m: caracter

cntf, cntm, i, : inteiro

inicio

cntf := 0

cntm := 0

para i de 1 ate 56 faca

escreva ("Digite seu nome: ")

leia (nome)

escreva ("Digite seu sexo (f/ m): ")

leia (sexo)

se (sexo = f) entao

cntf := cntf + 1

senao

fimse

se (sexo = m) entao

cntm := cntm + 1

senao

fimse

fimpara

escreval ("Total de homens: ",cntm)

escreval ("total de mulheres: ",cntf)

fimalgoritmo
```

Comment: Nao entendi. Que links?